# Dynatree - How to make parent nodes display the plus expand sign [+]?

Tags: parent, symbols, expand, dynatree

Having a Dynatree with nodes loaded in lazy mode, is there a way to tell him that a node is a parent before the children nodes being "lazily" loaded?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#tree").dynatree({
      width:300,
      title: "Lazy Tree",
      keyboard: true,
      persist: true,
      autoCollapse: true,
      clickFolderMode: 3,
      fx: {height: "toggle", duration:300},
    initAjax: {
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'treeNodes.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {key: 0},
    },
    onActivate: function(node) {
      node.toggleExpand();
      // Do this and that when some label is clicked
    },   
    onLazyRead: function (node) {
      node.appendAjax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "treeNodes.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {key: node.data.key}
      });
       } 
    });
});
```

MySQL request in treeNodes.php to load the nodes:

```
if ($parent==0) { // Load first level nodes
    $req = "SELECT name AS title, id AS 'key', isparent AS isLazy FROM `".$database['database']."`.`".$database['prefix']."categories` WHERE parent=0";
} else {  // Load sub-nodes from the given parent
    $req = "SELECT name AS title, id AS 'key', isparent AS isLazy FROM `".$database['prefix']."categories` WHERE parent=".$_POST['key'];
}
```

The `isparent` column stores if a node is parent or not.
Using it to set isLazy as 1 or 0 tells the tree to display with expandable nodes. But the nodes display with an "unknown status" (blue diamond icon) until they are clicked.

I'm looking for something equivalent to an "isParent" node parameter, so that as soon as it is displayed, each node comes with a [+] symbol if it does have children and no symbol else.

Answer (score 0):

- If you know that a node does not have children, set `"isLazy": false`, so no expander icon is displayed.
- If you know it has children, you could send them directly with the current request, so a `[+]` is displayed.
- If you know it has children, but you don't want to send them with the current request, set `"isLazy": true`, so a `[*]` is displayed. This indicates that the user can expect more nodes to be loaded on expand.
  You may override the icon to a `[+]` with custom CSS, of course.

p.s.
Note that DynaTree is no longer actively maintained. I recommend switching to [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree).

Comment: Thanks. isLazy is already set to false for all leaves, as their value in the isparent column is set to 0. But the [*] sign is displayed despite leaves are without children. For all parent categories, isparent is set to 1, so that isLazy is set to 1 (i.e. true). I don't see the interest of loading the (sub-)nodes before the user wants to see some of them. If having for instance 5 main categories and 100 nodes in each of them, it seems to me absurd to preload 500 nodes. I'm missing something?
Is Fancytree mainly a code rewrite of Dynatree and can one easily switch from Dynatree to it?

Comment: Migrating to Fancytree is pretty straight forward: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/WhatsNew

Comment: Thank you. I tried switching to Fancytree, adapting paths when necessary, but it did not work. I believe that I will stay with Dynatree for some time as it suits my needs. For Dynatree, is there some callback function that I could call at the end of the onLazyRead event processor to render the node icons? How does Dynatree/Fancytree render the nodes when onActivate occurs? Thanks.